# Protractor, need to create dictionary of key : value pair

Tags: javascript, protractor

I have a method to create key: value pairs of elements

```
this.cardcontent = function () {
    var cardcontents = {}; empty dictionary declaration
    var cardtext = element.all(by.css('.tileHeader')).map(function(cards) {
        return cards.getText();
    }); // card name as list in text format
    var contenttext =  element.all(by.css('.tileContentText')).map(function(content) {
        return content.getText();
    });//card content as list in text format
    for(var i=0; i<cardtext.length;i++){
        cardcontents[cardtext[i]] = contenttext[i]; // creating the dictionary 
    }
    return cardcontents;
};
```

The above method is called here:

```
it("Validate that card name to reflect multiple categories", function (){
    var cardandcontents = homePage.cardcontent();
    console.log(cardandcontents);
    for (var j in cardandcontents) {
        if (cardandcontents.hasOwnProperty(j)) {
            console.log("key : " + j + " value : " + cardandcontents[j]);
        }
    }
});
```

Output that I am getting is empty dictionary `{}`. Desired output in console:

> ```
> key : card1 value: content1 
> key : card2 value: content2
> key : card3 value: content3
> key : card4 value: content4 
> key : card5 value: content5
> key : card6 value: content6
> ```

Can someone provide me the solution to this problem. I am not getting the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

`map()` returns a Promise. http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.map

In `for` loop you are trying to treat `cardtext` as an array. You need to resolve a promises.